# Coordinator layout "layout_behavior" hide bottom navigation bar on all bottom tabs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I used **Coordinator layout** and `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"` on **Bottom Navigation Bar**.

This works fine for auto hiding Bottom Navigation bar but
I don't want to hide my Bottom navigation bar for all tabs, I want to hide it for selected tab like Home and Menu other tabs scrolling should not hide bottom navigation bar.
Is there any way to implement this with **Coordinator layout**?

Answer (score 0):

The scroll flag used within the attribute app:layout_scrollFlags must be enabled for any scroll effects to take into effect. This flag must be enabled along with enterAlways, enterAlwaysCollapsed, exitUntilCollapsed, or snap

[Coordinate Layout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)